# Adding script tag to document IE7 issue

Tags: javascript

My page throws an error in IE7 when I appending an script tag the body.

The error occurs on the line that is commented:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

cmSetClientID("90065468", false,"www9.blah.com","blah.com");  

 //--> 

</script>
```

This is how I append the script:

```
var scriptHolder = document.createElement('script'),
            body = window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
            fn =    "function doMyFn(){//dosomething}";
        scriptHolder.text = fn;
        body.appendChild(scriptHolder);
        window.parent.doMyFn();
```

Comment: I'm trying to imagine a situation where you'd have to do this (append a script Element to the DOM) rather than simply including an external `.js` and calling the function(s) only when needed, or dynamically including a `.js` file, or AJAX loading JS and using `eval()`, and I can't think of why one would do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Note: body tag schould be much easier to get: `document.body`

Another thing is to use `yourelement.innerHTML` to set the content.
If you are ao a normal page (no iframe etc...) `doMyFn();` should be enough to call your Fn

Hope this helps you

Comment: It was actually window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]. innerHTML for script tags not working in IE. You can't call parent window functions directly